# add an autoincrementing number in an object to the push

Tags: javascript, arrays, auto-increment

I have this function which adds an object inside this array:

```
 addSomething(array) {
  const something = {
    id: number
    defaulTimeStart: "08:00",
    defaultTimeEnd: "00:00",
    delete: true,
  };
  array.time.push(something); 
},
```

I would like the id to be a number starting for example from 0, and every time I push, that number increases by 1, so that every time I will have objects with different numbered ids like:

```
 array: [
  {
    id: 0
    defaulTimeStart: "08:00",
    defaultTimeEnd: "00:00",
    delete: true,
  },
  {
    id: 1
    defaulTimeStart: "08:00",
    defaultTimeEnd: "00:00",
    delete: true,
  },
  {
    id: 2
    defaulTimeStart: "08:00",
    defaultTimeEnd: "00:00",
    delete: true,
  },
  //etc.....
 ]
```

ATTENTION: I need this to be able to delete the added object using that id as an index for the .splice(id, 1)

Comment: May I ask what is the `time` of `array.time.push` supposed to be?

Answer (score 0):

```
id: array.length
```

instead of

```
id: number
```

to generate a new id as your array increments

Comment: sorry I didn't explain myself well, I added a specification in my question, and what you wrote wouldn't work

Answer (score 0):

You could use the current length of the array.time.length property for the id.

Based on your example it

```
something.id = array.length +1;
array.push(something);
```

or

```
array.push(something);
something.id = array.indexOf(something);
```

A problem with both examples would be, if you remove an item from the list, the ids will no longer be correct.

Another method would be, retrieving the last item from the array, reading the id there and setting the new item id to that id +1. (or 0, if no item exists)

```
const something = {
  id: array.length ? array[array.length-1].id + 1 : 0,
  defaulTimeStart: "08:00",
  defaultTimeEnd: "00:00",
  delete: true,
};
```

You have added something in your question, using splice with this id will result in other problems later on. Because splice might remove the wrong index later. It will only work for the first item. So you have to get to get the correct index of the item with that id.

```
function delSomething(array, id) {
  let possibleItem = array.filter((item) => item.id == id)[0];
  if (possibleItem && array.includes(possibleItem))
    array.splice(array.indexOf(possibleItem), 1);
}
```

If you wanna have a result where the ID can be dynamical, you have to make us of a function call to retrieve the id. - With this, there is no need to set an ID in any way.

```
const something = {
  getId: function getId() { return array.indexOf(this) },
  ...
}
```

Comment: in fact I have not specified it in this question, I would like to add an id which I will then need and then remove it without problems.
i tried your last example but it always adds me id: 0

Comment: I'm sorry, but then your example has a misleading information. I thought "array.time" is the array from your example. Because you use `array.time.push` to push the results. If `array` is the list mentioned in your question, you just have to remove .time on every element. - I corrected it here.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly what you want to achieve, I think the only way to be sure that an item ID is always equal to its index in the array is to re-assign IDs every time you push a new item or splice one or more existing ones.
In order to do it, you might add two custom methods to `Array.prototype`:

```js
Array.prototype.pushObjectWithId = function(obj) {
  this.push(obj);
  this.forEach((item, index) => item.id = index);
}

Array.prototype.spliceWithIdReset = function(index, elements) {
  this.splice(index, elements);
  this.forEach((item, index) => item.id = index);
}

const myArr = [];

function addSomething(array) {
  const something = {
    defaulTimeStart: "08:00",
    defaultTimeEnd: "00:00",
    delete: true,
  };
  array.pushObjectWithId(something);
}

// test

console.log('myArr (initial):', myArr);
addSomething(myArr);
addSomething(myArr);
addSomething(myArr);
addSomething(myArr);
console.log('myArr (after adding 4 items):', myArr);
myArr.spliceWithIdReset(2, 1);
console.log('myArr (after removing 1 item starting from index 2):', myArr);
addSomething(myArr);
addSomething(myArr);
console.log('myArr (after adding 2 more items):', myArr);
myArr.spliceWithIdReset(1, 3);
console.log('myArr (after removing 3 items starting from index 1):', myArr);
addSomething(myArr);
console.log('myArr (after adding 1 more item):', myArr);
```

Anyway, it seems to me that having IDs which keeps changing defeats the very idea of an ID. I think you should abandon the idea of being able

> to delete the added object using that id as an index for the .splice(id, 1)

and simply implement an auto-incremental ID (e.g. with `array.length === 0 ? 0 : Math.max(...array.map(item => item.id) + 1 )`), which will not change and will not necessarily correspond to the object index in the array.

Comment: It's not "the only way" when using `Object.defineProperty(something, 'id', { get: function() { return array.indexOf(this); })`, `something.id` will return an id referring to the index inside the array. So -1 if item was removed from it. Otherwise the correct index to use for splice. There is no need to reassign it over and over again when modifying the array.

Comment: @Christopher you are right, I did not think about it. Anyway there will always be the potential issue of having having several objects (the ones removed from the array, which might or might not be used somewhere else in the code) with the same ID. This would be an issue also with my proposed solution, that's why I tend to discourage the idea keeping aligned the object ID and its index in the array.